# SQL JOIN Different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have situation like this:

[image]

On one side I have a lot of different values, in this example: AUTO, STANDARD, INSTALACIJE

On other side I can have a lot of different values, in this example: AUTO, ODRZAVANJE, INSTALACIJE, TRADE

I need to make a join this two tables, but if in second table I do't have relevant value in first table, I need always use STANDARD to join from first table.

But problem is that I don't know how much different values I can have in second table that they don't have relevant value in table 1, but in this case will have relationship with STANDARD.

**If we don't have a pair from the left side, always use standard.**

Anybody can help?

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE()` function.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (word VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl1 (word) VALUES
('AUTO'),
('STANDARD'),
('INSTALACIJE');

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (word VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 (word) VALUES
('AUTO'),
('ODRZAVANJE'),
('INSTALACIJE'),
('TRADE');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT COALESCE(t1.word, 'STANDARD') AS t1_word, t2.word AS t2_word
FROM @tbl1 AS t1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tbl2 AS t2 ON t1.word = t2.word;
```

**Output**

| t1_word | t2_word |
| --- | --- |
| AUTO | AUTO |
| STANDARD | ODRZAVANJE |
| INSTALACIJE | INSTALACIJE |
| STANDARD | TRADE |

Comment: There's no point in having STANDARD in table 1

Comment: @MatBailie Yes and No :-) There is no point having t1 table at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.name, 'STANDARD'), t2.*
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1
ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: That works if you just want to add the value instead of a `null`, but if you actually need the data from the other columns on the `standard` (which would be the only reason to have a problem like this to solve I'd think) you probably want to do another join to bring that in, something like this `SELECT ISNULL(t1.name, ts.name), t2.* FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.name = t2.name LEFT JOIN t1 AS ts ON ts.name = 'STANDARD'`. Ofcourse, is hard to tell with the little information provided, so your answer is as good as any :)